# Take Contents of Oracle PL/SQL Table and insert into a Global Temporary table

Tags: oracle, plsql, collections, oracle11g

Using the code example from this PDF: https://thtech.files.wordpress.com/2012/12/apex_data_loading_options.pdf

I would like to replace all references to the Oracle APEX API APEX_COLLECTION (since I am not using Oracle APEX at all but just PL/SQL), but instead use a global temporary table to store the contents of the PL/SQL table, that is 
being used in this example (within PDF link above).

The main area I am having trouble with, is the `l_record` declaration of `varchar2_t` and how to take the following code:

```
  FOR i IN 1..l_record.count LOOP
    apex_collection.update_member_attribute(
        p_collection_name=> p_collection_name,
        p_seq => l_seq_id,
        p_attr_number => i,
        p_attr_value => l_record(i));
  END LOOP;
```

and replace the storing of l_record into a global temporary table `MY_GTT` below instead of an APEX_COLLECTION, that I can reference each column returned from l_record.

The part that I am not sure about is how can I take the contents of the PL/SQL type of `l_record` which is a `table of varchar2(32767) index by binary_integer` and store the contents as individual records, within MY_GTT?

I have declared a GTT as follows:

```
CREATE GLOBAL TEMPORARY TABLE MY_GTT
(
    SEQ_ID  NUMBER,
    C001    VARCHAR2(4000 BYTE),
    C002    VARCHAR2(4000 BYTE),
    C003    VARCHAR2(4000 BYTE),
    C004    VARCHAR2(4000 BYTE),
    C005    VARCHAR2(4000 BYTE),
    C006    VARCHAR2(4000 BYTE),
    C007    VARCHAR2(4000 BYTE),
    C008    VARCHAR2(4000 BYTE),
    C009    VARCHAR2(4000 BYTE),
    C010    VARCHAR2(4000 BYTE),
    C011    VARCHAR2(4000 BYTE),    
    C012    VARCHAR2(4000 BYTE),
    C013    VARCHAR2(4000 BYTE),
    C014    VARCHAR2(4000 BYTE),
    C015    VARCHAR2(4000 BYTE),
    C016    VARCHAR2(4000 BYTE),
    C017    VARCHAR2(4000 BYTE),
    C018    VARCHAR2(4000 BYTE),
    C019    VARCHAR2(4000 BYTE),
    C020    VARCHAR2(4000 BYTE)
)
ON COMMIT PRESERVE ROWS;
```

I'm getting the impression that what I am asking for here is not actually possible.

Comment: @APC Understand what you are saying but I guess I added the code in there for context. I will update my post but to drill right-down to my requirement is how can I take the contents of the PL/SQL type of l_record which is a table of varchar2(32767) and store the contents as individual records, within MY_GTT?

Comment: @APC Have updated my original question.

Comment: So is your question: *how do I split a 32k string into twenty 4K columns?*

Comment: @APC well the content is l_record which holds the content of an MS Excel.csv spreadsheet, around 16 columns of data and one example of 10 rows say. Using this example, I would expect to see 10 rows of 16 columns within MY_GTT. The remaining four columns from C017 to C020 would be NULL.

Comment: Have you considered using an external table? [Find out more](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/12.2/sutil/examples-using-oracle-external-tables.html#GUID-03CE63AD-F046-4805-A560-E4CFD7FA8503)

Comment: @APC Unfortunately I have inherited this code and need to keep to existing structure and do not have access to create external tables. Just for my understanding, I have two questions: 1) is this not possible, what I am asking here? 2) Is there any means of re-declaring the l_record as type table of my_gtt%rowtype index by binary_integer; but this then breaks `p_array(l_idx) :=` code in PDF within `csv_to_array` procedure?